# Infinite non-self-intersecting paths in graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph (of any cardinality).  Suppose all its vertices have finite degree.  Then does there exist an infinite non-self-intersecting path of an infinite sequence of vertices in $G$?

If not, then is it true if the supremum of the degrees in $G$ is finite?

I am comfortable assuming that $G$ is a tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, provided $G$ is connected. This is precisely the content of [König's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konig%27s_lemma).